# Delete Folders on Remote PC with Certain names

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, rmdir

This is a sample code that allows me to delete all folders with the name ".RemoveAsap" attached to them

```
@echo on
set dir="\\TestPC2\c$\Users"
FOR /D /R %dir% %%X IN (*.RemoveAsap) DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%X"
pause
exit
```

Simply running the code as is runs perfectly but when I try to make the code more interactive, I get the error

```
@echo on
cd C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Test\
TYPE con >> LowDASD.txt
For /F %%A in (LowDASD.txt) do echo "\\%%A\c$\users\" >> LowDASD2.txt
set "LwDs"="LowDASD2.txt"
FOR /D /R "%LwDs%" %%X IN (*.RemoveAsap) DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%X"
pause
```

LowDASD2.txt would be the address/ directory location where the directories will be deleted, IE `\\TestPC2\c$\Users`

The code does not delete anything or give an error that "the path is too long" at least it was doing that with the previous variations that I was trying. If someone can help me with this, i would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `set "LwDs"="LowDASD2.txt"` will set a variable called `LwDs"` to the value `"LowDASD2.txt`. You need `set "LwDs=LowDASD2.txt"` to set `LwDs` to `LowDASD2.txt`.

Comment: @Magoo, I just tried set `"LwDs=LowDASD2.txt"` but it did not work, but I finally got a 
different variation of set and it seems to have worked `< LowDASD2.txt set /p "LwDs="` <br> My only issue now is that the script does not timeout and stop, it the folders are deleted but the scrip remains there and does not go onto the next line. What do you recommend that I to remedy this?

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /D /R "%LwDs%" %%X IN (*.RemoveAsap) DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%X"
```

Simply will not work, as `%LwDs%` is a filename.

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%j in ("%LwDs%") do  FOR /D /R "%%j" %%X IN (*.RemoveAsap) DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%X"
```

You would think might work - `%%j` being assigned to each entry in the `%LwDs%` file in turn; `usebackq` used because the filename is "quoted" (see `for /?` from the prompt for documentation)

But it doesn't - the `for /d /r` syntax doesn't accept metavariables...

So - try

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%j in ("%LwDs%") do set "target=%%j"&call :expunge
```

Where `expunge` is an internal subroutine. The colon is *required*

```
:expunge
echo target="%target%"
FOR /d /r "%target%" %%X IN (*.RemoveAsap) DO echo RMDIR /S /Q "%%X"
echo ====================
goto :eof
```

An internal subroutine should be placed after an unconditional `goto`, which should in your case follow the `pause`

```
pause
goto :eof
```

Where `:eof` (compulsory colon again) is defined as the physical end-of-file and should **not** be used as a user-label. Reaching physical end-of-file returns from a `call`.

Always verify against a test directory before applying to real data.

Note that the `rmdir` is merely being `echo`ed for testing purposes - remove the `echo` keyword after testing to activate.

=== Extension

The full code should thus be

```
@echo on
set dir="\\TestPC2\c$\Users"
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%j in ("%LwDs%") do set "target=%%j"&call :expunge
pause
exit
:expunge
echo target="%target%"
FOR /d /r "%target%" %%X IN (*.RemoveAsap) DO echo RMDIR /S /Q "%%X"
echo ====================
goto :eof
```

Comment: Hey @Magoo, apologies for the late reply, I had been sick so didn't have time to follow up. Anyhow I tried running the updated script above and here is the error that i received

`The system cannot find the file`
`target=""`
`The full path of  is too long.`

I tried using it with both the `rmdir` and `echo rmdir` and I am still getting the error, here is the script
``
`set "LwDs"="LowDASD2.txt"`
`FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%j in ("%LwDs%") do set "target=%%j"&call :expunge`

`:expunge`
`echo target="%target%"`
`FOR /d /r "%target%" %%X IN (*.RemoveAsap) DO RMDIR /S /Q "%%X"`

Comment: I've added what the full code should look like - obviously, the `echo`es are optional. If you have the `:expunge` routine locate directly after the `for /f ...%%j...` then batch will `call` that routine with each entry in the file, and then execute it again as it simply executes the next instruction - it has no concept of `sections`, `paragraphs`, `functions` or `procedures`.

Comment: The report appears to say that `target` contains the string `target=""`; but it's difficult to tell - what does the `echo target="%target%"` report? There is a chance that a directory exceeds ~1024 characters, which may generate that error. I've had this happen when there's a `link` in a directory that points to itself. Unfortunately, `chkdsk` does not detect this situation. I'd suggest `ntfslinksview` by `Nirsoft` to find this situation. `dir/s/b` from the starting directory might also indicate where the problem lies.

Comment: I've been out and about with work but after much work and your assistances, I've got a working script – 
`echo Deleting files in Drivers Folder`
`For /F %%A in (LowDASD.txt) do rmdir /Q /S "\\%%A\C$\Drivers\"`

`echo Deleting .RemoveAsap User Folders`
`For /F %%A in (LowDASD.txt) do dir /ad /b \\%%A\C$\Users > Users00.txt`

`TYPE Users00.txt  | findstr /v /i /r "All Users" | findstr /v /i /r "Default" | findstr /v /i /r "Default User" | findstr /v /i /r "Public" | findstr /v /i /r "TEMP" > users01.txt`

`TYPE Users00.txt | findstr /I /R .Asap >> users03.txt`

Comment: `< LowDASD.txt set /p "PcList="`
    `(for /F "delims=" %%A in (users03.txt) do echo rmdir /s /q \\%PcList%\c$\users\%%A >> users04.txt)`

    `find /i /c "Asap" users03.txt > NUL`
    `if %errorlevel% equ 1 goto notfound`
    `For /F %%A in (users03.txt) do Echo Removing the following users %%A`
    `cmd<users04.txt >nul 2>&1`
    `goto Outlook`

    `:notfound`
    `echo No RemoveAsap Users Found`
    `echo:`
    `goto Outlook`

Answer (score 0):

Try using **FORFILES**, instead of the command **FOR**, this way you can make it work like this:

```
:: forfiles /p "folder_location"  'args' '/c "cmd /c del /f /q @path"'

:: So...

cd C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Test\
TYPE con >> LowDASD.txt
For /F %%A in (LowDASD.txt) do echo "\\%%A\c$\users\" >> LowDASD2.txt

set "LwDs=LowDASD2.txt"

forfiles /p %LwDs% /s /c "cmd /c del /f /q @path"
:: You can use '/d -90' to delete files older than 90 days in the folder
```